# Copy rows in the same table with recursive dependency inside

Tags: mysql, sql, copy, hierarchical-data

I have the some tables in MySQL database

```sql
create table pages
(
    id              bigint       not null,
    organization_id bigint       null,
    parent_id       bigint       null,
    language_tag    varchar(2)   null,
    type            varchar(7)   null,
    theme           varchar(19)  null,
    status          varchar(7)   null,
    title           varchar(256) null,
    image           text         null,
    image_hover     text         null,
    sort            int          null,
    created_at      timestamp    null,
    updated_at      timestamp    null,
    constraint pages_id_uindex
        unique (id),
    constraint pages_pages_id_fk
        foreign key (parent_id) references pages (id)
            on update cascade on delete cascade
);

create table blocks
(
    id          bigint        null,
    page_id     bigint        null,
    title       varchar(256)  null,
    content     longtext      null,
    readmore    longtext      null,
    image       varchar(1024) null,
    image_hover varchar(1024) null,
    type        char(9)       null,
    sort        int           null,
    constraint blocks_pages_null_fk
        foreign key (page_id) references pages (id)
);
```

As you can see `parent_id` is a reference to its own table `id`.

I want to copy some specific rows with all its children. I couldn't write a simple insert query because I cannot know `parent_id` of parent page that not existing yet. Also, relation is recursive and not plain. Some children could have another children, e.t.c Just like a tree. I could make it nullable, but then I have to update all children manually. And I have `blocks` relation entity that have to be copied too. It's a quite terrible amount of work. Could you give me advice how I can resolve this issue with the simplest way?

Comment: Create SELECT which selects all rows to be inserted, then add INSERT clause simply.

Comment: and how to insert parent_id of non-existing row? How to explain to SQL what exectaly id should be in right place?

Comment: Do you have MySQL 8.x? You can use a recursive CTE to follow all the parent links.

Comment: If not, you'll have to write a procedure to follow the links.

Comment: if you don't want to mess with cte and coursor, you can just delete constraint pages_pages_id_fk and after insertion return it back